# Table talk strategy

Tags: live

In the live poker games I've been playing, there has been lots of table talk.  Everyone gets involved.  Some questions they ask include:

- Do you want me to call that bet?
- Do you have the flush?
- Do you want me to raise?

etc.

As a beginner to live poker, I'm unsure of how I should answer such questions and what the possible implications my answer will have in the opponent's mind.  I understand some people say to just avoid it all together, but I'd rather not do that and learn to play the table talk game - which seems to be a game in itself.

Are there some basic principles of table talk that I should know as a beginner ?  For example: should my table talk be consistent with my bets - e.g. if I raise, should I always say I want them to call etc. ?

Comment: You just put me in a very hard situation: on the one hand, this is an excellent question whose answers can delve deep into the very core of poker. It would be beautiful. On the other hand, I strongly feel I have to close it since it's kind of broad. I'll try to edit it in order to keep it open because it's a really great topic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had no choice. I couldn't find any way to make it more specific. If anyone does, then please edit it and vote to re-open, I'll be happy to oblige :)

Comment: Watch how the pros do it on TV.  It can be controversial, e.g. Jamie Gold in the 2006 WSOP.

Answer (score 1):

The question **is** too broad. You're asking how to angle. Angling is basically just an attempt to gather information on your opponents ranges/hand by acting a certain way or saying certain things. It's not allowed in most casinos (although that rule isn't really enforced much) and is strictly banned in WSOP/EPT/etc. events.

There is far, far too much about this to answer it in one question. It's highly situational and opponent dependent. You should listen to the people telling you to ignore anything and everything people are saying to you. You aren't obligated to answer them and if you do answer them you'll likely do it in such a way that you give them exactly the information they're looking for.

Focus on playing a solid game and observe how other players are angling. Question the implications of their actions and estimate whether it had a net positive or negative effect in the hand. Then, as you grow experienced and acquainted with the more common spots and such (while maintaining an image and pose that is hard to read and difficult to angle), you can start to implement said angling versus opponents that aren't aware what you're doing.

There are lots of poker players out there, even professionals, who consider this poor etiquette. You can make money playing poker without angling others but it really depends on your preferences. Many people consider it a fundamental part of poker. I personally angle the hell out of people.